# SD card "broken" - changes in files do not persist over reboot

Tags: filesystems, sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi which is run from a micro SD card. It boots fine and dandy, but there's something peculiar going on. If I for instance create a new file and reboot, the file is not there. For example:

```
$ ls
$ echo 'bar' > foo.txt
$ ls
foo.txt

// HERE BE REBOOT //
$ ls
$
```

When I run other commands, e.g. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, it always installs the same updates. For some reason there's no persistence whatsoever - the file system has frozen in-place.

How do I fix this? There's nothing of value on the SD card, so I'd be comfortable with wiping it and re-installing the OS. However, when I tried to `dd` a new image to the card, it proceeded as expected, but when I booted up the Pi, the old OS still persists.

Comment: I have the same problem quite often. Your SD card is "old" and the filesystem gets corrupted often. A `fsck.ext3` often solves it until it corrupts again. Best advice is buying a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Your partition is probably corrupted. Run `fsck` from your desktop:

```
fsck.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

Where *sdb1* is your `root` partition in the SD.

Comment: Did my answer solves your problem? @manabreak

Comment: It didn't work for me.